# Running batch file cannot find default Python

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to run a python batch file from the command prompt. I have added the folder to my system variable, however, when I try to run the script using the command prompt I get at 'cannot find default python' message. What am I doing wrong?

I am working through automate the boring stuff by Al Sweigart. This is the map it project if you are familiar.

batch file below:

```
@py.exe C:\Users\foste\Documents\Programming\automate_the_boring_stuff\Chapter 11\map_it.py %*
@pause
```

I expect to be able to type in map_it in the command prompt along with a string and open a webbrowser going to google maps, mapping the address contained in the string.

Comment: Please post the **complete, exact** error message you're getting, not a paraphrased version of it.

Comment: The command prompt literally says 'Can't find a default Python.'

Comment: Try `Py "C:\Users\foste\Documents\Programming\automate_the_boring_stuff\Chapter 11\map_it.py" %*`